# nested form rails 4 save existing record on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I am struggling to get this working. I have three models

1. Student
2. Classroomattnd
3. Classroom

Using the has_many :through relationship. All my relationships are defined correctly and I have setup the nested form using the accepts_nested_attributes.

So when creating a new student I want to select from a list of classrooms instead of creating a new classroom. The form part also works fine the part I am not getting is when I create the student it complains about the following error.

Couldn't find Classrooom with ID=3 for Student with ID=

I have searched around for few days now but can not get the answer I need to get this working.

```
def new
  @student = Student.new
  @student.classrooms.build
end

def edit
end

def create
  @student = Student.new(student_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @student.save
      format.html { redirect_to @student, notice: 'Student was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @student }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Can someone help here, someone must of face this issue before?

Also in the rails console when I run the following it works:

```
classroom = Classroom.last
student = Student.create(name: 'Dave', classrooms:[classroom])
```

Comment: Looks from that blank ID like you aren't getting student fields. How is "student_params" getting defined?  I'd expect to see something more like params[:student].

Comment: the student params are defined as below in the controller:
    def student_params
      params.require(:student).permit(:name, classrooms_attributes:[:id, :name ])
    end @elc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameter handling isn't supporting nesting.  You can look at request parameters in your server log or inspect the fieldnames of your generated form to be sure of your target.  It's going to be something along the lines of

```
def student_params
  params.require(:student).permit(:student => [:name, :classroom => [:id, :name]])
end
```

Or maybe as below.  In this second case I'm not assuming everything in the form is nested under a student container.  Also note the switch from classroom to classroom_attributes which is a change I have sometimes needed to make even though the form above is what the docs indicate.

```
def student_params
  params.require(:name).permit(:classroom_attributes => [:id, :name])
end
```

Hopefully that gives you a notion of how to tailor your parameter definition to what your form is generating.  Also note your error messages give you indication of what part of your definition is failing, eg the missing Student id in the error you quote.

Comment: Thanks @elc that did the trick I think, well at least I am not getting the same error anymore, I will take care of it from here now.